# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notifications.role_id' in 'where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Buen día, agradezco a todos aquellos que se toman la molestia de leer mi inquietud

Estoy haciendo unas notificaciones con los roles, es decir cuando se autentiqué fulano tal, le traiga los notificaciones vinculadas al rol, tengo tres roles a los cuales puede darse el caso que una misma notificación debe salirle a los tres

estoy tratando de hacer esto en el modelo  notification:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','direct_id');
     switch (Auth::user()->role_id)
     {
        case 2:
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','manag_id');
        break;
        case 3:

        break;
        case 4:
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','coord_id');
        break;
    }
}
```

El switch lo hice para validar quien  esta iniciando sesión y dependiendo del rol me devuelva la relación que necesito y de ese modo traer esas notificaciones vinculadas al rol

o no se si haya otra forma de relacionar esas tres foráneas a la tabla rol, dependiendo de la persona que esta autenticada

modelo rol:

```
public function notification(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification');
}
```

}

En mi vista home tengo esto :

```
 @foreach(Auth::user()->role->notification as $n)
            @if ($n->v==1)
                <div class="card shadow-sm mx-4 mb-0 my-2 border-primary">
                    <div class="card-header font-weight-bold text-light bg-primary"><i
                            class="fas fa-bell"></i> {{$n->notification}}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <strong>Solicita:</strong>
                        <p>{{$n->workpermit->user->people->names}}</p>
                        <strong>Tiempo Solicitado:</strong>
                        <p>{{$n->workpermit->timepermit}} Horas</p>
                        <strong>Tipo de permiso:</strong>
                        <p>{{$n->workpermit->typepermit->name}}</p>
                        {{--  {{$n->workpermit->description}}--}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <form action="{{route('approve.WorkPermit',
                        ['WorkPermitId'=>$n->workpermit_id,'off'=>0])}}"
                              method="post">
                            @csrf @method('PATCH')
                            <label for="approvepermit" class="my-2 font-weight-bold">Desea aprobar el
                                permiso?</label>
                            <select name="approvepermit" class="form-control mb-2 " id="approvepermit">
                                <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
                                <option value="0">Denegar</option>
                                <option value="1">Aprobar</option>
                            </select>
                            <button class="btn btn-success">aceptar</button>
                            <a href="{{route('details.WorkPermit',$n->workpermit_id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver
                                detalles</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @else
                <p class="mx-4">No hay notificaciones nuevas</p>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

y el error es este:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notifications.role_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notifications` where `notifications`.`role_id` = 3 and `notifications`.`role_id` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Según lo que comprendo del error hay un campo role_id que esta null, creo que es de la relación que hace eloquent, si es asi, como puedo decirle que el campo será manag_id,direct_id o coord_id o no se si conocen una forma diferente de hacerlo

Les agradecería un montón si pudieran sacarme de esto, espero haberme dado a entender, con palabras no sabría como explicárselos

Comment: ¿Nos mostrarías tu consulta por favor?, además agregarías la relación inversa, es decir la del modelo Role?

Comment: Además basándonos en [ask] te agradecería expliques mejor que es lo que tratas de hacer, no termino de entender el problema base y además por que en la relación haces ese switch

Comment: @BetaM listo amigo, espero haberme dado a entender

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tenemos una estructura como la siguiente:

- **`User`**
- **`Rol`**
- **`Notification`**

Donde:

- Un usuario tiene un rol y un rol pertenece a un usuario
- Un rol puede tener muchas notificaciones

Entonces los modelos deberían lucir mas o menos así:

**Modelo `User`**

```
public function rol()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

**Modelo `Role`**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class);
}
```

**Modelo `Notification`**

```
public function roleNotification()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Ahora en el caso de las consultas, lo primero que debemos obtener es el id del usuario que se autenticó así:

```
$authenticatedUser = auth()->user()->id;
```

Ahora si lo que deseamos es obtener todas las notificaciones de este usuario basándonos en su rol, podemos construir la consulta así:

```
$userWithNotifications = User::query()
                              ->with('rol.notifications')
                              ->findOrFail($authenticatedUser);
```

**Comentarios**

- Es decir el modelo `User` no tiene relación directa con las notificaciones, pero esta relación es alcanzable por medio de `roles`
- No veo necesidad del **`switch`** y de hecho lo considero mal aplicado, para obtener la información del rol con el que se inició sesión eso lo podemos hacer directo en la misma consulta

Comment: No sé si me hice entender bien, yo hago la consulta en la vista es decir Auth::user()->role->notification, lo hice está forma ya que puedo traer notificaciones vinculadas tanto a la persona como el rol, o no se si te entendí mal, la consulta que hiciste en qué modelo iría?

Comment: No poseo controlador para eso, por eso no mostré consultas, en un inicio trate de retornar una variable al Home desde un controlador comparando los respectivos id, pero arrojaba error la variable x no está definida

Comment: ahora que tenga un compu cerca detallo más mi consulta, perdona error mio, no doy bueno explicando

Comment: Y por qué no tienes un controlador? No creo que nada te lo impida, salvo que sea un requerimiento, en algún lado debes meter la consulta, si te da algún error es distinto y se puede solventar, pero no por eso debes descartar un controlador

Comment: Lo voy a intentar de nuevo y te muestro el error, te agradezco mucho la ayuda, aún me falta mucho por aprender de laravel